# Changing Document Path Apache Mac Sierra

Tags: macos, apache

I have followed all the steps from https://medium.com/@JohnFoderaro/how-to-set-up-apache-in-macos-sierra-10-12-bca5a5dfffba#.scwat9ihp to start my web server . Need help

On running apachectl -S

```
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "/usr/local/opt/httpd24"
Main DocumentRoot: "/usr/local/var/www/htdocs/"
Main ErrorLog: "/usr/local/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex default: dir="/usr/local/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/usr/local/var/run/apache2/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="daemon" id=1 not_used
Group: name="daemon" id=1 not_used
```

I have changed /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
#ServerName www.example.com:80
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">

DocumentRoot "Users/{{username}}/Sites/"
<Directory "Users/{{username}}/Sites/">
```

I have added private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
#Virtual Host Entry for foo.localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/{{username}}/Sites/foo"
  ServerName foo.localhost
  ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/foo-error_log"
  CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/foo-access_log" common </VirtualHost>
#Virtual Host Entry for bar.localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/{{username}}/Sites/bar"
  ServerName bar.localhost
  ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/bar-error_log"
  CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/bar-access_log" common 
</VirtualHost>
```

But apache seems to run index.html file on '/usr/local/var/www/htdocs/' instead of "Users/{{username}}/Sites/"

Answer (score 0):

If you are followed that document for latest version of Sierra then it wont help you to get through. because it happened to me also.

- Revert the following two steps, **/etc/apache2/httpd.conf** and **I have added private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**
- Just go to **httpd.conf** file then find the following lines **Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews**.If this exits then just add **Indexes** after **Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews** and restart the server

This is help the system to access the files **"/Library/WebServer/Documents/"** itself and no longer you need to change the document path.